# Code Only WCF Hosting has "localhost" in the link to the wsdl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, wsdl, service-reference

I have a wcf service that I am self hosting in an console app.

When I run the service and deploy it to a machine (call it MyWCFRunningMachine) I can go to the "You have created a service" page.  (http://MyWCFRunningMachine:8090/MyService).

But then it gives a link to the wsdl page.  That link looks like this: http://**localhost**:8090/MyService?wsdl

So when I click on that link it tries to connect to the service using my machine rather than MyWCFRunningMachine.

If I cold type in the path to the wsdl (http://MyWCFRunningMachine:8090/MyService?wsdl) then I see a wsdl in the browser.  But if I try to add a service reference I get this error:

> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
>     - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>     - There was an error downloading 'http://**localhost**:8090/MyService?xsd=xsd0'.

This is also referencing localhost when it should not.

Here is the code I am using to self host my service:

```
public class SelfServiceHost
{
    static string StartUpUrl {get{return "http://localhost:8090/MyService";}}
    static void Main(string[] args) { StartupService(StartUpUrl); }

    public static ServiceHost StartupService(string startUpUrl)
    {
        //+ Setup the Service
        //Create a URI to serve as the base address
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri(startUpUrl);
        //Create ServiceHost
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), httpUrl);
        //Add a service endpoint
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        //Enable metadata exchange
        ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior =  
             new ServiceMetadataBehavior {HttpGetEnabled = true};
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);

        //! Turn on Debug.  Remove for production!
        host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof (ServiceDebugBehavior));
        ServiceDebugBehavior serviceDebugBehavior = 
            new ServiceDebugBehavior {IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true};
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDebugBehavior);

        //Start the Service
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is hosted at " + httpUrl);
        Console.ReadLine();

        return host;
    }
}
```

How can I get this to remove the localhost?  (NOTE: I cannot hard code it to MyWCFRunningMachine.  This service will be run on several different machines.

Do I need to go with a config file that I change as I move machines?  (I have stayed away from a config file because I did not want to set one up for my console app, but if it is the only way, then I will do it.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct in using a config file to hold the machine name

"http://" + MACHINE_NAME + ":8090/MyService"

After the service has been installed, change that value in the config file and restart the service to bring it in.